# There’s no “OUT_BYTES” field when I parse netflow through logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

As title, when I use logstash to parse netflow(from cisco_f7) and ingest flow data into ElasticSearch, and I found the data in ES is lack of `OUT_BYTES` field. I have searched for a long time, and some people have the same problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

This is a document of the netflow data in ES:

```
{
  "_index": "netflow-%{year}-%{month}-%{day}",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "QnjmS2EBwY8ORgd4n7yl",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "netflow": {
      "in_pkts": 13,
      "version": 5,
      "src_tos": 0,
      "engine_type": 1,
      "ipv4_next_hop": "120.127.163.193",
      "dst_as": 0,
      "dst_mask": 0,
      "sampling_algorithm": 0,
      "src_mask": 0,
      "flow_records": 24,
      "output_snmp": 0,
      "last_switched": "2018-01-31T10:58:40.971Z",
      "first_switched": "2018-01-31T10:58:40.971Z",
      "ipv4_dst_addr": "120.127.163.193",
      "tcp_flags": 0,
      "ipv4_src_addr": "216.58.200.234",
      "protocol": 6,
      "src_as": 0,
      "input_snmp": 191,
      "l4_dst_port": 10029,
      "sampling_interval": 0,
      "l4_src_port": 443,
      "in_bytes": 5548,
      "flow_seq_num": 1259678413,
      "engine_id": 2
    },
    "@timestamp": "2018-01-31T10:58:44.972Z",
    "host": "120.127.163.4",
    "@version": "1"
  },
  "fields": {
    "netflow.first_switched": [
      "2018-01-31T10:58:40.971Z"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-01-31T10:58:44.972Z"
    ],
    "netflow.last_switched": [
      "2018-01-31T10:58:40.971Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

logstash config:

```
input{
    udp{
        host => "120.127.XXX.XX"
        port => 5556
        codec => netflow    
    }
}
output{
elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["120.127.XXX.XX:9200"]
                index => "netflow-%{year}-%{month}-%{day}"
            }

        stdout{codec=> rubydebug}

}
```

Anyone can help me?
thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see any out_bytes field in your netflow example document.

Comment: I don't know how to see netflow document directely, but when I parse netflow through nProbe and ntopng it has out_bytes field. So you mean maybe there's no out_bytes correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, see also https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-netflow/issues/11. If the field could not be parsed, you should see an error message in the log.